# what will happen if i connect 6 TEC module in series? will it give high COP?

Tags: peltier

i m working in a project of peltier cooler .i want high cop as possible .so i want to ask of i connect 5-6 TEC module for extra cooling then will it work properly ? or can it give high cop?

Comment: Please write your question using the normal rules of English. For example, the pronoun "I" is always capitalized. And a period is put immediately after the letter preceding it, with a space after each period.

Answer (score 0):

Putting them in parallel is just the same as using a physically larger device.

Putting them in series is hard work. The one at ambient has to shift not only the heat from cold end, but also the dissipation of all the TEC's colder than it. This means you have a pyramid of TECs, with a very tiny one at the cold end, and a huge one at ambient.

I've never seen more than a three stage, and the pyramid looked silly in the research paper. Two stages is not quite so impractical. There's a very good reason most are used in a single stage.

If you need more cooling than a single stage, it's worth looking at other types of cooler, before you stack on another TEC.

Comment: Someone recently here put up an answer and a link to his paper/research on stacking TEC for an old question. Four was thelit with present technology. We should dig it up.